# Помогите соединить две функции в одном файле Python. Юзербот на pyrogram

Tags: python, asyncio, pyrogram

Помогите исправить код, чтобы в одном файле можно было запустить одновременно две функции, где
async def auto_answer - отвечает за автоответ на сообщения, а async def main - за рассылку. У меня запускается только одна функция.

```
#данные бота
api_id = 
api_hash = 

interval = float(input('время задержки в секундах:____'))
text = ''
chat_ids = []

app = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

# автоответчик
text2 = ''
sp_p = []

@app.on_message(filters=filters.private)
async def auto_answer(event, message):
    if message.from_user.id not in sp_p:
        await app.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=text2)
        print(f'Пользователь отправил сообщение: {message.text}')
        time.sleep(0.25)
        sp_p.append(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        pass
        print(f'Получено новое сообщение: {message.text}')

# рассылка
async def main():
    async with app:
        async for dialog in app.get_dialogs():
            if dialog.chat.type in [ChatType.GROUP, ChatType.SUPERGROUP]:
                for chat_id in chat_ids:
                    try:
                        await app.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
                        print(f'Сообщение отправлено в группу: {chat_id}')
                    except Flood as e:
                        print(f'Не удалось отправить сообщение в группу: {chat_id}')
                    except UserBannedInChannel as e:
                        print(f'Спам блокировка. {chat_id} ')
                    except NotAcceptable as e:
                        print(f'Не удалось отправить сообщение в группу: {chat_id}')
                print('Рассылка выполнена.')
                time.sleep(interval)

app.run(main())
```

Comment: asyncio.create_task(main())

Comment: не помогло.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Может кому пригодится, вот код.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import time
import asyncio

# Данные бота
api_id = 
api_hash = ''

interval = float(input('Время задержки в секундах: '))
text = ''
chat_ids = []

text2 = ''
sp_p = []

client = Client('me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)


@client.on_message(filters=filters.private)
async def auto_answer(_, message):
    global sp_p
    if message.from_user.id not in sp_p:
        await client.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=text2)
        print(f'Пользователь отправил сообщение: {message.text}')
        time.sleep(0.25)
        sp_p.append(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        print(f'Получено новое сообщение: {message.text}')


async def main():
    global chat_ids
    while True:
        for chat_id in chat_ids:
            try:
                await client.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
                print(f'Сообщение отправлено в группу: {chat_id}')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Ошибка при отправке сообщения в группу: {chat_id}')
        print('Рассылка выполнена.')
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)


async def run():
    await asyncio.gather(client.start(), main())


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```